# Swing Table - rows

Tags: java, swing

I have to build a table with one column,exactly 24 rows and with function to add more columns.
Each row must have a specific height, which I do with cell renderer.
The problem is that the 21 row shrink and when I add a column it look fine.
What is the problem?

Comment: In such a case, without any line of code, you'll have to admit this question is quite hard to answer.

Comment: ok but how can i set heigth on each row on a swing table

Comment: invoke prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) on your table for each cell with an instance of javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer where you have implemented your custom repaint method.

Comment: could you give me some example please

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JTable table = new JTable();
JTable table = new JTable();

table.setRowHeight(32);
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {
    public int getColumnCount() { return 1; }
    public int getRowCount() { return 24;}
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return "Your content" }
});
frame.add(table);
frame.pack();
frame.setEnabled(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the height of the rows:

myTable.setRowHeight (24);

works with both Default and AbstractTableModels
Now if I only could find a way to make the height of the header same as the rows!
Anybody went there? Thanks, - M.S.